# Access parent property in handlebars each where each is nested property

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars to iterate over a nested array and display the data using a handlebars template, but I need to access a property that is not part of the array that I am iterating over. When the array is not nested, this works as expected. Here is an example (you can paste these directly into [tryhandlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)):

Template:

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">
    {{#each items}}
      <p>{{name}} - {{quantity}} {{../currency}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Data:

```
{
  currency: 'GBP',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'apples',
      quantity: 5
    }, {
      name: 'bananas',
      quantity: 7
    }
  ]
}
```

But now I have a requirement to pass a whole new data structure to the template, so I am wrapping the fruit data as a property of another object:

```
{fruit: {
  currency: 'GBP',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'apples',
      quantity: 5
    }, {
      name: 'bananas',
      quantity: 7
    }
  ]
}}
```

I change the `#each` to iterate over `fruit.items` instead of `items`:

```
{{#each fruit.items}}
  <p>{{name}} - {{quantity}} {{../currency}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Now, the name and the quantity are outputted correctly as before but the currency is blank. It seems the relative reference using `../currency` no longer works. The only difference is the dot notation in the value passed to the `each`. How can I use the relative path in a nested property?

I have tried creating a helper function that takes the relative reference so I can inspect the values and can see the currency reference is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little confusion here as to what the parent context is when within the `#each`.

As a tip, a good way to discover the parent context is to use Handlebars' built-in [log helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#log).

Within our `#each` we can add `{{log ..}}` and Handlebars will print to the console the value of our parent.

In this case we get:

```
{
  fruit: {
    currency: 'GBP',
    items: Array(2) [...]
  }
}
```

This tells us that our parent is the root context and not the `fruit` object. This makes sense because we never "step-into" the context of `fruit` - for example, by using `{{#with fruit}}{{#each items}}` - but instead iterate `fruit.items` directly from the root.

This means we need only change our `../currency` to `../fruit.currency`. An alternative would be to use Handlebars' [@root data variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#root) to jump to our root context directly: `@root/fruit.currency`.

A second alternative is to use the `#with` helper as mentioned above. This creates a `fruit` context, allowing us to leave the `#each` part of the template as you had it in your post:

```
{{#with fruit}}
  {{#each items}}
     <p>{{name}} - {{quantity}} {{../currency}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/khc930p7/) for your reference.